# Sophisticated builder methods with Expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

Let's say I've to create the following method in runtime

```
Type someType = ...; // assigned somewhere

var method = (presenter) => 
{
    var instance = new SomeType(); // I've only default constructor here
    instance.SomeProperty = presenter;
    return instance;
}
```

Does anybody know how can I create such method in runtime using Expression trees?

Comment: Do you know the type of `presenter` at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Basically, a presenter type is available from generic, so we can easily get the type from typeof(TPresenter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to use `Expression.Block` to get the multi statement lambda. You can use something like:

```
void Main()
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "presenter");
    var instance = Expression.Variable(typeof(Foo), "instance");
    var ctor = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    var block = Expression.Block(new [] { instance },
        Expression.Assign(instance, Expression.New(ctor)),
        Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(instance, "SomeProperty"), p),
        instance
    );

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,Foo>>(block, p);
    Foo f = lambda.Compile()(5);
    Console.WriteLine(f.SomeProperty);
}

class Foo 
{
    public int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Of course you need to tweak this to fit your needs, which parts are variable and which are not, and so on, but it demonstrates the general idea.